# How to pass output of one command to other command& how to delete only that files which are not in the result of commad?

Tags: shell

I am writing shell script for following scenario: 1) find logfiles that were modified 2 weeks(or more) before.2) From this output find which of them are currently in use.3)Delete unused files. For this I have tried these commands: 1) find /tmp/.log -mtime +14 | xargs /usr/shraddha/backup 2) lsof -c umaiproxy| grep /usr/shraddha/backup. It is giving me result of 2 weeks before modified file but currently in use. But I don't want to save the result of first command in directory. Instead of that I want to pass output of first command as an input to second command. And how to write command to delete files which are not in the result?

Answer (score 0):

Store output of first command in a variable e.g.

```
TEMP=`command1`
```

then pass this variable to second command e.g.

```
command2 <<< $TEMP
```

Comment: Result of first command is list of files as mentioned in question.So from that list I have to find out currently being used files.And delete files which are unused.How I can do that?

Comment: you can use "$TEMP" to list variable value in multiple line.

>    for i in "$TEMP"
>    do
>    rm $i
>    done